# React js, Assigning a key to an object within the constructor behave weird

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a constructor of Reactjs, I call `myFunc()` written below. This function randomly selects an item from questions array and assigns a key called `"showed"`, before returning.

What I am having trouble with that is it assigns all items in the questions array `"showed"` key instead of one.

```
const questions = [
  {
    question: "What are you doing",
    answers: [
      {
        _id: 1,
        answer: "Working !",
      },
      {
        _id: 2,
        answer: "Nothing",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    question: "What should you be doing",
    answers: [
      { _id: 1, answer: "Working more!" },
      { _id: 2, answer: "This is enough" },
    ],
  },

];

export function myFunc() {
  const unAnsweredQuestions = questions.filter((x) => x.showed != true);

  console.log("unasnwered", unAnsweredQuestions);

  const randomInteger = Math.floor(Math.random() * unAnsweredQuestions.length);

  questions[
    questions.indexOf(unAnsweredQuestions[randomInteger])
  ].showed = true;

  console.log("why this is happening?", questions);
  return unAnsweredQuestions[randomInteger];
}
```

In constructor

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("App constructor");

    this.state.questionSource = myFunc();
}
```

Here what I see in the console:

[image]

What I am doing wrong, I couldn't figure out

Comment: When you set `showed = true` you're modifying the original questions object, not just the state in your component. If there's more than one instance of your component, or if your component re-mounts, those "showed" modifications are going to accumulate. Is that your intent?

Comment: My intention is just to assign the picked item showed = true value so that it doesn't return again with the help of "filter ( x => x.showed != true)". But it assigns "showed = true " all items in the array. By the way, I am a bit novice in react js, but don't think it remounts

Answer (score 0):

I can't really explain what's going on with your current approach. I suspect React is instantiating your component more than once, and each instantiation mutates the array questions.

Here's an alternate approach that makes a copy of the questions array, sorts it into a randomized order, and uses its [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#iterators) to step through the questions.

There's a [live version](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-kare-yir5m?file=/src/App.js) of this on codesandbox.

```
// utility function that copies an array and randomizes the order
const randomize = (arr) => [...arr].sort((a, b) => Math.random() - 0.5);

const Questions = () => {
  // Get a randomized iterator of the questions.
  // useRef so we don't get a new instance on every render
  const { current: iterator } = React.useRef(
    randomize(questionSet)[Symbol.iterator]()
  );

  // initialize component state with the iterator's first question
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(iterator.next().value);

  // if the iterator didn't return a value we're done.
  // otherwise, render the question and a button to advance
  return !current ? (
    <div>Done</div>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <div>{current.question}</div>
      <ul>
        {current.answers.map(({ answer }) => (
          <li key={answer}>{answer}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <button onClick={() => setCurrent(iterator.next().value)}>Next</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return <Questions />;
}

const questionSet = [
  {
    question: "What are you doing",
    answers: [
      {
        _id: 1,
        answer: "Working !?"
      },
      {
        _id: 2,
        answer: "Nothing"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: "What should you be doing",
    answers: [
      { _id: 1, answer: "Working more!" },
      { _id: 2, answer: "This is enough" }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort, it will absolutely help me